# Which virtualization software like vmware but open source can be installed on directly onbare metal?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, redhat-enterprise-linux

Which virtualization software like vmware but open source can be installed directly on bare metal?

Is it possible with oVirt?

Answer (score 0):

[oVirt](http://www.ovirt.org/Home) is a management application for kernel based virtual machine ([KVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine)) guests, so the answer is definitely no. oVirt is not a hypervizor and does not run on bare metal.

When it comes to open source hypervisors, there aren't much else but KVM and Xen coming close to your requirements. So, a second answer to your question about oVirt is that you can run oVirt to manage KVM virtual machines, so that is a partial yes.

For some clarification on terminology and a partial list for hypervisors which might do what you probably are looking for, see [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor).

Comment: Thanks Sami for quick reply! I have visited both Wiki Links. I have understood KVM also requires base Linux OS, so we can not say purely Type 1 native hypervisor. But Xen is pure hypervisor? couldn't understand that.

Comment: Neither is bare metal in the sense I think you're using the term. Xen comes closer, but still requires something to manage it as dom0. Usually that's a GNU/Linux or NetBSD for example.